# I need to redirect my url to another url using haproxy

Tags: haproxy

I need to redirect http://localhost:8080/client to http://localhost:8080/client/legacy automatically using haproxy.

can anyone please help me on this, I don't have any idea as I am beginner in this.

I tried placing frontend and backend section in haproxy.cfg file in this way but that doesn't work

```
frontend http-in
    bind *:80
    mode http
    http-request redirect location /client/legacy if { path_beg -i /client }
    default_backend http-backend

backend http-backend
    mode http
    server web1 127.0.0.1:8080 check
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [sf] would be better places for questions like this.